# Alternative to using filter() with includes()

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two Objects that look more or less like this :

```
export const recipes: Recipe[] = [
  new Recipe( id: "Green", scenario: ["1", "2"]),
  new Recipe( id: "Blue", scenario: ["1", "2","2"])
];
```

```
export const scenarios: Scenario[] = [
  new Scenario( id: "1", ...),
  new Scenario( id: "2", ...)
];
```

Inside my Recipe model I created a function to retrieve my Scenario by their `id: string` :

```
  getScenario(): Scenario[] {
    return scenarios.filter(scenario => this.scenario.includes(scenario.id));
  }
```

This function filters every scenario that matched the `id: string`.

My problem is that, if my property `scenario: string[]` contains the same `id: string` multiple time, it'll still give me an array with `["1", "2"]` and not `["1", "2","2"]`, which is the result I want.

Comment: What do you mean *"doesn't work"*? What output were you expecting? Give a [mcve]. Also this doesn't seem to relate to Angular at all, except that presumably this model is being used in an app.

Comment: I expect function that can return scenarios (```id: string```) multiple time in an array.

Comment: The way those classes are typed is proper to Angular using typescript. It makes sense to include this tag.

Comment: It doesn't use any Angular features at all, this is just vanilla TS. Also your example input seems to be the same as your input, and if you expect the output to be the same length as the input you `.map` not `.filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are filtering `scenarios`, which means each scenario (1, 2, 3 etc.) is going to be accessed once. You need to reverse the order and loop through `this.scenario`

Because you can't use filter here as you actually need the scenario stored in the `scenarios`, your `getScenario()` function should be

```
getScenario(): Scenario[] {
    return this.scenario.map(scenarioValue => scenarios.find(s => s.id == scenarioValue));
  }
```

Comment: Abishek, small typo in your code: should be `map()`.

Comment: this is it. Thanks

Comment: @AbishekAditya Beat me by a second haha nice!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` instead.

```
getScenario(): Scenario[] {
  return this.scenario.map(scn => scenarios.find(s => s.id === scn));
}
```

This will take all the values inside of the `recipe.scenario` and convert them to `Scenario`.